# How can i get sum of particular column in grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to show the sum of particular column in grid view and show it on top of that column. 
  Note: Data is coming from database.
This is my gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="SalesSummaryGrid" OnPageIndexChanging="SalesSummaryGrid_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="SalesSummaryGrid_RowDataBound" 
                        PageSize="10" CssClass="mydatagrid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"  RowStyle-CssClass="rows"
                      PagerStyle-CssClass="pager" AllowPaging="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                       <Columns>
                          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Apr">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="AprMonth" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Apr") %>' CssClass="labelstyle"></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                          </asp:TemplateField>
                       <Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you please share some of your code. This question is overtly broad.

Comment: _"and show it on top of that column"_ - outside of gridview?

Answer (score 3):

In the RowDataBound for Footer, you can do FindControl on the HeaderRow of the GridView to find Labels in the Header. Then you can set the values of these.

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView4.Rows) {
    if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        decimal fee = Convert.ToDecimal(gvr.Cells(5).Text);
        feeFooter += fee;
    }
}
GridView4.Columns(3).HeaderText = feeFooter;
```

Source : https://forums.asp.net/t/1812651.aspx?GridView+Totals+in+Header

Comment: same with LINQ: `GridView4.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>().Where(r => r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow).Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Cells[5].Text))`

Comment: i tried this but there are build errors. not working for me as i expected.

Comment: Please explain the build errors as there should not be any due to standard api without any custom component or namespace required here